# Repeating notifications issue

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm struggling with notifications.

I want to randomly select text to display in the notification (using **random()** method on the array of String objects from separate object file **NotificationData** where I only had one immutable variable called **notificationData**), which should appear once a day at a specific time (but for now, for the purpose of the test, I wrote in the code to appear every hour). I'm using **AlarmManager** for scheduling. The first thing is the notifications does not appear at the specified hour when the app is not currently working (or during the device sleep mode), but after launching the app. And second thing is that after launching the app, notifications appear almost one by one within few seconds. I don't really understand why it happens in this way. It's quite strange for me.

Here's the **NotificationUtils** class, where I create my notification and put one String from Array inside **setContentText()** method:

```
package com.example.quit.notification

class NotificationUtils(context: Context) {
    private var mContext = context
    private lateinit var notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder
    val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext)
    private val CHANNEL_ID = "Notification_Channel"

    init {
        createNotificationChannel()
        initNotificationBuilder()
    }

    fun launchNotification() {
        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext)) {
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = "Rady"
            val description = "Codzienne rady dla zdrowiejących osób uzależnionych"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply {
                this.description = description
            }

            val notificationManager: NotificationManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

    private fun initNotificationBuilder() {
        val sampleIntent = Intent(mContext, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, sampleIntent, 0)

        val data = NotificationData.notificationData.random()

        notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_support)
            .setContentTitle("Rada na dziś")
            .setContentText(data)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
    }
}
```

Second class, where I create repeating alarm:

```
package com.example.quit.notification

@SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")
class AlarmUtils(context: Context) {
    private var mContext = context
    private var alarmManager: AlarmManager? = null
    private var alarmIntent: PendingIntent

    init {
        alarmManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmIntent = Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { mIntent ->
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 100, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
    }

    fun initRepeatingAlarm(calendar: Calendar) {
        calendar.apply {
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        }

        alarmManager?.set(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.timeInMillis,
            alarmIntent
        )
    }
}
```

Here's my **AlarmReceiver**, where I set next alarm after one hour in this case (:

```
package com.example.quit.notification

class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val notificationUtils = NotificationUtils(context!!)
        notificationUtils.launchNotification()

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1)
        val alarmUtils = AlarmUtils(context)
        alarmUtils.initRepeatingAlarm(calendar)
    }
}
```

In **AndroidManifest.xml** file I only added one line in  tag:

```
<receiver android:name=".notification.AlarmReceiver" />
```

And the last thing - in **MainActivity** class I put those three lines just after **setContentView()** method:

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val alarmUtils = AlarmUtils(this)
alarmUtils.initRepeatingAlarm(calendar)
```

I'll be very grateful for any help and explanations.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is used for questions/issues about the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: What device are you testing this on?

Comment: @DavidWasser I'm testing the app on Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 with Android 10

Comment: Some devices (notably low-end and Chinese manufacture) restrict apps from running in the background (or from starting automatically). On these devices you need to add your app to a list of "protected apps" or a list of "apps allowed to run in the background" or something similar. This may be why your app is not launched from the `AlarmManager` if it is not already running. Check if your device has something like this (usually in security or power management settings)

Comment: While I concur with @DavidWasser, I also recommend reviewing https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious why your notifications appear immediately. In `AlarmReceiver` you do this:

```
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1)
    val alarmUtils = AlarmUtils(context)
    alarmUtils.initRepeatingAlarm(calendar)
```

You want to take the current time, add one hour and schedule an alarm at that time (1 hour in the future). However, look at what `initRepeatingAlarm()` is doing:

```
    calendar.apply {
        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20)
        set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
        set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    }
```

in `initRepeatingAlarm()` you are setting the hour, minute and seconds to a fixed value (which is the time that the alarm originally went off). You are overwriting the time that was set in the `Calendar` that was passed in. In this case, when the alarm is set, the time is in the past so the alarm triggers immediately.

---

Regarding why the alarms do not work when the device is sleeping, the call to `AlarmManager.set()` is not considered "exact" and the system may delay the alarm to ensure that the device is not constantly awakened (preservation of battery). See this [explanation found in the documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager?hl=en#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

If you want the alarm to go off at exactly this time, you need to use a different method, such as `setExact()`, and you will need to declare an additional permission `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` (if you target API level 31 or higher)

Comment: How can I effectively and easily distinguish the first call of **initRepeatingAlarm()** and the other ones in future?
I've moved the **calendar.apply{...}** in conditional statement `if(calendar < Calendar.getInstance())` to set the fixed values for the first time (because the calendar object created in **MainActivity** is before the one created in **if** statement. Even though the first alarm didn't execute.
I've changed `set()` to `setExact()` method and added the `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM`.

Comment: You could add a boolean parameter to `initRepeatingAlarm()` which when `true` means called for the first time, otherwise `false`. Or you could pass `null` as the `Calendar` parameter to mean "first call".

Comment: Were you able to solve the rest of the problems?

Comment: Ok, I'll check this solution today.

Comment: About solving the rest of the problems: I've allowed my app to run in the background in the device settings and you were right - it helped with appearing notifications at the fixed time when the app was not running (there were many notifications in the same time ofc, but I'll try to fix it today as you suggested).

Comment: Ok, the boolean parameter works well. Thank you. I still have one last problem - I'm setting the fixed value to 9:00 AM in `initRepeatingAlarm()` and setting the next notification to be executed the next day. But when I launch the app, the first notification appears instantly. I want to show the first notification tomorrow at 9AM, not today every time launching the app...

Comment: Then you need to set the date properly. You've obviously set the date for today, not tomorrow. If you set an alarm for a date in the past, it triggers immediately. That's how `AlarmManager` works.